# Blender exports GLB 1000x too large

Tags: export, transforms

So when I am creating Blender files (textured and animated) for Augmented Reality, since there is no proper USDZ export (as far as I understand) I have been exporting as GLB and converting them to USDZ using a variety of formats (Playground website, or Reality Composer). I work in Blender in mm (Industrial Designer) but when I export the files and reopen them in Blender they are 1000x larger.

I cannot see any export scale settings for exporting GLB. How can I ensure they come out the right size?

Comment: AFAIK Blender's unit scales are really just a display thing, they do not really change the scale of what you make. If you want to model something in mm, you should keep the default scene unit (Meter) and scale down your model so that it is the right scale in that unit display. Then, some formats and softwares have different scales than Blender, so you have to "know" them and pre-adapt your model for it. Most of the time, exporters just add a scale multiplicator to your objects, they don't actually resize the scale (they don't "Apply the scale" in Blender's terms).

Comment: I have the model the size I want it to be. Then I export as GLB, but if I open the GLB it is 1000x larger. This messes up textures and things (but movement still is the same). If there's no solution I guess there's no solution.